# Generic UITableview Cell

Tags: ios, swift, uitableview, generics

I want to create a tableview with customs cells, each cell is different. But i want the implementation to be so smart.
I thought instead of making if else check in `cellForRow:atIndex:` for every cell like this

```
if indexpath.section == 0 {
  // Create first cell
} else if indexpath.section == 1 {
  // Create second cell
}
```

and so on..

I decided to create a protocol like so:

```
protocol tableviewProtocol {
  func cellForAt(index: IndexPath, object: ObjectModel) -> UItableviewCell
}
```

and for every cell i want to show i create a class like so:

```
class firstCellClass: tableviewProtocol {
    func cellForAt(index: IndexPath, object: ObjectModel) -> UItableviewCell {
       // create and return the cell
    }
}
```

and created this array,

```
var tableviewDataSource: [tableviewProtocol] = []
```

and then fill the array like so:

```
tabletableviewDataSource = [firstCellClass(), secondCellClass(), thirdCellClass()]
```

and in tableView `cellForRow:atIndex:`

```
return tableviewDataSource[indexpath.section].cellForAt(indexpath, object: object)
```

And that was fine until i have to create different cell with different object model type instead of `ObjectModel`

So how can i make it more generic that can accept any type of objects ?

Comment: Just so I understand, your data model holds different classes of data in the same array and you want to dequeue a different cell class based on the type of data?

Comment: @nighttalker I have different cell and each cell will represent different data model, so what. i want is to find a way to make it generic that can accept any type of model and build the cell from that.

Comment: Why not create a protocol for the data models, say ObjectModelProtocol, and typecast/downcast it to the correct class in the cellForAt method?

Answer (score 0):

You can make it more generic by subclassing UITableViewCell

```
class firstCellClass: UITableViewCell {

}

class secondCellClass: UITableViewCell {

}

class thirdCellClass: UITableViewCell {

}


let arrayOfCells = [UITableViewCell]()
```

Something like this should point you in the right direction. There are many ways to achieve this goal

Comment: I don't think this the solution i was looking for, I was looking for more generic solution, something like a protocol every class could implement and it could accept any type of model.

and every class implement this protocol with their own different model and return the cell.
your solution is basically allow me to write anything in each class and this not what i was looking for.

Comment: @Islam.Ibrahim yes, I misinterpreted the question. I provided another answer. Check it out

Answer (score 0):

I realize this isn’t the most elegant way to do it but hopefully it helps you.

Let’s say you have three types:

```
struct ModelA { ... }
struct ModelB { ... }
struct ModelC { ... }
```

So you can make the array of type `Any`:

```
var model = [[Any]]() // append data
```

Then in `cellForRow`:

```
var cell: UITableViewCell

let value = model[indexPath.section][indexPath.row]

switch val {
case is ModelA:
    cell = tableView.dequeueReusableCell(withIdentifier: "cellA", for: indexPath) as! CellClassA
case is ModelB:
    cell = tableView.dequeueReusableCell(withIdentifier: "cellB", for: indexPath) as! CellClassB
case is ModelC:
    cell = tableView.dequeueReusableCell(withIdentifier: "cellC", for: indexPath) as! CellClassC
default:
    cell = UITableViewCell()
}

return cell
```

Answer (score 0):

Nighttalker had a good answer to just use "Any" but you could also try 2 other ways:

1. Make ObjectModel a protocol, and make all objects you want to pass in implement that protocol

   ```
   protocol ObjectModel{

   }

   class SomeObject: ObjectModel{}
   ```
2. Use generics

   ```
   protocol tableviewProtocol {
       associatedtype ObjectModel
       func cellForAt(index: IndexPath, object: ObjectModel) -> UITableViewCell      
    }

   class SomeObject: tableviewProtocol{

        typealias ObjectModel = String //whatever type you want

        func cellForAt(index: IndexPath, object: ObjectModel) -> UITableViewCell{
       //return your cell
        }

    }
   ```